# Ubuntu 22.04 monitors display settings are not saved

Tags: 22.04, display

I have a very weird problem starting Ubuntu 22.04.

This is a fresh install, i have a GPU where one of my monitors is plugged, and the other one is plugged on the motherboard (both are HDMI).

If i logout, or if my computer goes into hibernation, sometimes my display settings goes:

- from **JOINT DISPLAY**
- to **MIRROR DISPLAY**.

I can't get a hold of what is going on, i tried many solutions like copying ~/.config/monitors.xml to other locations as suggested, but nothing works.

Here is my monitors.xml file

```
<monitors version="2">
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>1920</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-1-0</connector>
          <vendor>IVM</vendor>
          <product>PL2480H</product>
          <serial>11183V3601718</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-2</connector>
          <vendor>IVM</vendor>
          <product>PL2480H</product>
          <serial>11183M5101249</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-1-2</connector>
          <vendor>IVM</vendor>
          <product>PL2480H</product>
          <serial>11183M5101249</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>1920</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-0</connector>
          <vendor>IVM</vendor>
          <product>PL2480H</product>
          <serial>11183V3601718</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-2</connector>
          <vendor>IVM</vendor>
          <product>PL2480H</product>
          <serial>11183M5101249</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
  <configuration>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>0</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <primary>yes</primary>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-1-2</connector>
          <vendor>IVM</vendor>
          <product>PL2480H</product>
          <serial>11183V3601718</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
    <logicalmonitor>
      <x>1920</x>
      <y>0</y>
      <scale>1</scale>
      <monitor>
        <monitorspec>
          <connector>HDMI-0</connector>
          <vendor>IVM</vendor>
          <product>PL2480H</product>
          <serial>11183M5101249</serial>
        </monitorspec>
        <mode>
          <width>1920</width>
          <height>1080</height>
          <rate>60</rate>
        </mode>
      </monitor>
    </logicalmonitor>
  </configuration>
</monitors>
```

When i list active monitor using xrandr:

```
$ xrandr --listactivemonitors
```

output

```
0: +*HDMI-1-2 1920/521x1080/293+0+0  HDMI-1-2
1: +HDMI-0 1920/521x1080/293+1920+0  HDMI-0
```

The question then would be: Is there a problem with my configuration file monitors.xml ? If not, would you have some hints on from where it comes from or some docs on how monitors.xml configuration syntaxe please ?

Thanks